# символ u200b, что это такое?

Tags: python, excel

Имеется ексель файлик, с которого дергаю столбец, и заношу в массив, если запринтить массив целиком, появляются символы /u200b, если же выводить каждый элемент отдельно, этого символа нет.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import re


wb = xw.Book('new.xlsx')
data_excel = wb.sheets['Details']
# data_pd = data_excel.range("D1").expand().value

data = data_excel.range('D1').expand().options(pd.DataFrame, header = 1, index = False).value # 



rewrite = data['Обнаруженный объект'].values


Threats = []
newThreats = []

for i in rewrite: 
    if i not in Threats:
        Threats.append(i)

for k in Threats:
    k.replace('u200b','')
    print(k)
    newThreats.append(k)



print(newThreats)
```

вывод консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2):

u200b — это невидимое пространство.
Когда u200b встречается в конце строки, компьютер воспринимает его как пробел и переносит. Когда u200b встречается в середине строки, компьютер просто пропускает его.

```py
i.replace('\u200b','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на проблемы кодировки в исходном файле.
Данный символ в Unicode означает некий хитрый пробел - подробнее [тут](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)

Можно попробовать следующее:

- сконвертировать excel в csv и читать csv
- проверить кодировку исходного файла